# Не центрируется текст в кнопке

Tags: html, css

По разному пробовал, но в кнопке которая удаляет элемент из ToDo листа не центрируется текст, в чем дело?

```js
let addbutton = document.querySelector('.AddButton');
let ol = document.querySelector('.ol');
let li = document.createElement('li');
let input = document.querySelector ('.input');
li.className = 'elem'; 

addbutton.onclick = function addElem(){
    if (input.value === '') return
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let deletebutton = document.createElement('button'); 
    li.innerHTML = input.value;
    li.className = 'elem';
    ol.append(li);
    input.value = '';

    deletebutton.className = 'deletebutton';
    deletebutton.textContent = 'x';
    li.appendChild(deletebutton);

    deletebutton.onclick = function(){
        ol.removeChild(li)
    }
    
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.ToDoBox{
    width: 385px;
    height: 625px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin-top: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.AddButton{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.AddButton:active{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.elem{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.ol{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.input{
    margin-top: 14px; 
    margin-left: 12px;
    color: white;
    height: 27px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #b0850e;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.deletebutton{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 0px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.deletebutton:hover{
     background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="ToDoBox">
        <button class="AddButton">+</button>
        <input type="" name="" class="input">
        <ol class="ol"></ol>
    </div>

    <script src="javas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст-то центрируется - по горизонтали. Но съезжает по вертикали - из-за `line-height` у текста. Попробуйте добавить `.deletebutton` свойство `line-height: 0`:

```js
let addbutton = document.querySelector('.AddButton');
let ol = document.querySelector('.ol');
let li = document.createElement('li');
let input = document.querySelector ('.input');
li.className = 'elem'; 

addbutton.onclick = function addElem(){
    if (input.value === '') return
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let deletebutton = document.createElement('button'); 
    li.innerHTML = input.value;
    li.className = 'elem';
    ol.append(li);
    input.value = '';

    deletebutton.className = 'deletebutton';
    deletebutton.textContent = 'x';
    li.appendChild(deletebutton);

    deletebutton.onclick = function(){
        ol.removeChild(li)
    }
    
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.ToDoBox{
    width: 385px;
    height: 625px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin-top: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.AddButton{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.AddButton:active{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.elem{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.ol{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.input{
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    color: white;
    height: 27px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #b0850e;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.deletebutton{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #363636;
    border: 0px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
}

.deletebutton:hover{
     background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

```html
<div class="ToDoBox">
  <button class="AddButton">+</button>
  <input type="" name="" class="input">
  <ol class="ol"></ol>
</div>
```